Flutter Provider does not update UI when navigating
I display the device name on screen 1.
I try to set deviceName from screen 2 and then navigate back.
The UI does not update even tho in my print after the setDeviceName says the variable is updated.
My code where I navigate:
globalStateProvider.setDeviceName('name');
print(globalStateProvider.deviceName); (prints new name)
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, WidgetAnimator(MainWidget(), 0));

What I have tried:
import 'package: flutter/cupertino.dart';

class GlobalStateProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  String _deviceName = '';

  String get deviceName => _deviceName;

  setDeviceName(String newName) {
    _deviceName = newName;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
// Global value to access the whole app
final globalStateProvider = GlobalStateProvider();

Then I just call from my files:
globalStateProvider.setDeviceName('name');

globalStateProvider.deviceName;

Other try:

Declare the globalStateProvider everywhere I need it.

final globalStateProvider =
        Provider.of<GlobalStateProvider>(context, listen: false);

So in all my widgets where I want to use it I just declare it and call the functions. But this does not work.
Other try:
Provider.of<GlobalStateProvider>(context, listen: false).setDeviceName('');

Consumer<GlobalStateProvider>(builder: (context, state, child) {
        return Text(state.deviceName), 
      }),

Still, nothing works...

You are using listen: false in you second option, remove this if you want your widget to rebuild when there are changes to your provider object. Also please share the code where you consume it.

I cannot pass true, I get this error:
E/flutter ( 5351): This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
E/flutter ( 5351): Provider.of without passing listen: false.
E/flutter ( 5351):
E/flutter ( 5351): To fix, write:
E/flutter ( 5351): Provider.of(context, listen: false);

That is why I'm asking you to share the part of the code where you are consuming it. Without the context it is hard to know what you are doing wrong. Just follow what @albert221 said and it should work.

You cannot use
final globalStateProvider = GlobalStateProvider();

provider works in such a way, that it provides the values down the widget tree in BuildContext. You need to provide your globalStateProvider using Provider or Provider.value widget somewhere at the root of your app first to be able to listen to its changes.
However, as you're using ChangeNotifier, you will need a ChangeNotifierProvider specifically. For your case though, if you really want to have the globalStateProvider as a global variable, you can just use ListenableBuilder and pass it as a listenable. Thanks to this, the subtree return in ListenableBuilder.builder will be rebuilt each time this listenable called notifyListeners.
